# Same variables different values across testing

Tags: java, oop

I have this Java assignment to do which involves multiple different classes. To check the assignment we are given a test file which we cannot modify. The main class that is being tested is PricedHotel. I am passing every test except the last assertion test. After using the debugger I found that the room and safe in the PricedHotel class is different than the room and safe in the Test class, I'm not sure why this is happening I thought I referenced them properly. Can anybody help?

PricedHotel class:

```
package ss.week2.hotel;

import ss.week2.hotel.bill.Bill;
import ss.week2.hotel.bill.BillPrinter;
import ss.week2.hotel.bill.StringBillPrinter;
import ss.week2.hotel.PricedRoom;

public class PricedHotel extends Hotel {

    public static final double ROOM_PRICE = 100.0;
    public static final double SAFE_PRICE = 20.0;
    public PricedRoom r1;
    public Room r2;

    private Guest g1;
    private Guest g2;
    private StringBillPrinter stringBillPrinter;

    public PricedHotel(String name){
        super(name);
        r1 = new PricedRoom(1,ROOM_PRICE,SAFE_PRICE);
        r2 = new Room(2, new Safe());
        stringBillPrinter = new StringBillPrinter();
    }

   @Override
    public Room checkIn(String guestName) {
        Room room = super.checkIn(guestName);

        if (!(room instanceof PricedRoom)) {
            PricedRoom pricedRoom = new PricedRoom(room.getNumber(), ROOM_PRICE, SAFE_PRICE);
            pricedRoom.setGuest(room.getGuest());
            room = pricedRoom;
        }

        return room;
    }


    public Bill getBill(String guestName, int total, BillPrinter billPrinter){
        PricedRoom room = this.r1;
        PricedSafe safe = (PricedSafe) this.r1.getSafe();
        Bill bill = new Bill(billPrinter);

        if (safe.isActive()) {
            Bill.Item item1 = new Bill.Item() {
                @Override
                public double getPrice() {
                    return ((total*ROOM_PRICE) + SAFE_PRICE);
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return guestName;
                }
            };
        } else {
            Bill.Item item1 = new Bill.Item() {
                @Override
                public double getPrice() {
                    return total*ROOM_PRICE;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return guestName;
                }
            };
            bill.addItem(item1);
        }
        return bill;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
package ss.week2.hotel.tests;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import ss.week2.hotel.*;
import ss.week2.hotel.bill.Bill;
import ss.week2.hotel.bill.StringBillPrinter;
import ss.week2.hotel.password.Password;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class PricedHotelTest {
    /** Test variable for a <tt>Hotel</tt> object. */
    private PricedHotel hotel;
    private String correctPassword;
    private String wrongPassword;
    public static final String GUEST_NAME_1 = "Major Gowen";
    public static final String GUEST_NAME_2 = "Miss Tibbs";
    public static final String GUEST_NAME_3 = "Miss Gatsby";

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS = 5;

    /**
     * Sets the instance variable <tt>hotel</tt> to a well-defined initial value.
     * All test methods should be preceded by a call to this method.
     */
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        hotel = new PricedHotel("Fawlty Towers");

        // initialisation of password-variable
        correctPassword = new Password().getInitPass();
        wrongPassword = correctPassword + "_invalid";
    }

    /**
     * checkIn First room should be a PricedRoom
     */
    @Test
    public void testCheckIn() {
        Room room = hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_1);
        assertTrue(room instanceof PricedRoom,
                "room should be an instance of PricedRoom");
        Safe safe = room.getSafe();
        assertTrue(safe instanceof PricedSafe,
                "safe should be an instance of PricedSafe");
    }

    /**
     * If there is a free room, getFreeRoom must return a room without guest.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetFreeRoomFromNotFullHotel() {
        Room room = hotel.getFreeRoom();
        assertNull(room.getGuest(), "A room is free");
        hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_1);
        Room freeRoom = hotel.getFreeRoom();
        assertNotNull(freeRoom, "Another room is free");
        assertNotEquals(room, freeRoom, "Another room is free");
    }

    /**
     * If there is no free room, getFreeRoom must return null.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetFreeRoomFromFullHotel() {
        hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_1);
        hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_2);

        Room noRoom = hotel.getFreeRoom();
        assertNull(noRoom, "No room available in a full hotel");
    }

    /**
     * getRoom must not return any room, if the guest is not checked in
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetRoomBeforeCheckIn() {
        Room room = hotel.getRoom(GUEST_NAME_1);
        assertNull(room, "Guest 1 not checked in");
    }

    /**
     * If the guest is checked in, the returned room must be occupied by the specified guest.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetRoomAfterCheckIn() {
        hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_1);
        Room room = hotel.getRoom(GUEST_NAME_1);
        assertEquals(GUEST_NAME_1, room.getGuest().getName(), "Guest 1 checked in");
    }

    /**
     * A password object must be returned.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetPassword() {
        Room room = hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_1);
        assertTrue(room instanceof PricedRoom,
                "room should be an instance of PricedRoom");
        Safe safe = room.getSafe();
        assertTrue(safe instanceof PricedSafe,
                "safe should be an instance of PricedSafe");

        Password password = ((PricedSafe) safe).getPassword();
        assertNotNull(password, "Returned password is not null");
    }

    /**
     * The Bill should be correctly calculated
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetBill() {
        Room room = hotel.checkIn(GUEST_NAME_1);
        assertTrue(room instanceof PricedRoom,
                "room should be an instance of PricedRoom");
        StringBillPrinter printer = new StringBillPrinter();
        Bill bill = hotel.getBill(GUEST_NAME_1, NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS, printer);
        double nightsTotal = NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS * PricedHotel.ROOM_PRICE;
        assertEquals(nightsTotal, bill.getSum(), 0.01, "Bill sum should contain only room costs.");
        assertTrue(printer.getResult().contains(String.format("%.2f", nightsTotal)));

        // Now check sum again when safe is actually active
        assertTrue(room.getSafe() instanceof PricedSafe);
        PricedSafe safe = (PricedSafe) room.getSafe();
        assertFalse(safe.isActive(), "Safe should be deactivated after initialisation.");
        safe.activate(correctPassword);
        assertTrue(safe.isActive(), "Safe should be activated after activation with password.");
        Assertions.assertEquals(nightsTotal + PricedHotel.SAFE_PRICE,
                hotel.getBill(GUEST_NAME_1, NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS, printer).getSum());

    }
}
```

Hotel.checkIn class:

```
public Room checkIn(String name){
        if (room1.getGuest() != null && room2.getGuest() != null){ //checks if the two rooms are empty
            return null;
        }

        if (g1 != null && Objects.equals(g1.getName(), name)){ //checks if g1 is already checked in
            return null;
        }
        if (g2 != null && Objects.equals(g2.getName(), name)){ //checks if g2 is already checked in
            return null;
        }

        Room freeRoom = getFreeRoom(); //gets a free room
        if (freeRoom == null){ // checks if hotel is fill
            return null;
        }

        Guest newGuest = new Guest(name); //new guest object with the name we provided
        newGuest.setRoom(freeRoom); // set's the new guest to the free room
        freeRoom.setGuest(newGuest); // set's the guest to the free room

        if (g1 == null){
            g1 = newGuest;
        } else if (g2 == null) {
            g2 = newGuest;
        }
        return freeRoom;
    }
```

Comment: Can you name a test that fails so we do not have to run your code in order to find out what your problem is?

Comment: This is the test that fails ```Assertions.assertEquals(nightsTotal + PricedHotel.SAFE_PRICE,
                hotel.getBill(GUEST_NAME_1, NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS, printer).getSum());``` It outputs 500 when it should output 520

Comment: Look closely at `PricedHotel.checkIn` - if it creates a `PricedRoom` it does not set `this.r1` .  This means the result of `checkIn` and `hotel.getBill` are not using the same room instance which affects your test.  Would need to see `Hotel.checkIn` to confirm this.

Comment: I added Hotel.checkIn class hopefully it helps

Comment: So it is the case that `checkIn` will create a new `PricedRoom` but it does not set `this.r1` and so `getBill` uses `r1` but your test uses the result of `checkin` (which is a different room instance) to then manipulate the safe - so this is wrong.  Just set `this.r1` in the `PricedHotel.checkin` where you create the new `PricedRoom` instance.  As an aside, you very well could just use the room variables of the parent class without having to create new room variables in the subclass - provided `PricedRoom` does not change the behavior of its `Room` properties (LSP). Your tests were good!

Comment: I changed the checkIn to `PricedRoom pricedRoom = r1;` but still the same issue is happening

Comment: The only line you need to add is `this.r1 = pricedRoom` in that method inside the conditional block.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it makes the actual value 0.0 when 520.0 is expected

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you so much man!